# Polymorphism in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, polymorphism

Trying out polymorphism in TypeScript I found out about kind of a weird behaviour. At least I consider this a weird behaviour with myself coming from Java, where rules tend to have a much stricter tendency than in TypeScript.

So, I created a little example that showcases TypeScript only respecting the structure, but not the logical thought behind implementing and using interfaces in classes.

```
interface Bird {
    tweet(): string;
}

class Crow implements Bird {
    constructor(private message: string) { }

    tweet(): string {
        return this.message + "<br />";
    }
}

class Sparrow implements Bird {
    constructor(private message: string) { }

    tweet(): string {
        return this.message + "<br />";
    }
}

class ManWithAHat {
    constructor(private message: string) { }

    tweet(): string {
        return this.message + "<br />";
    }
}

class Chitter {
    static do(bird: Bird): string {
        return bird.tweet();
    }
}

// Getter for num returned 4
let element = document.getElementById('content');
let output: string = "";

const crow = new Crow("Crow says something!");
output += Chitter.do(crow);

const sparrow = new Sparrow("Sparrow says something!");
output += Chitter.do(sparrow);

const manWithAHat = new ManWithAHat("A man with a hat shouldn't be able to talk!");
output += Chitter.do(manWithAHat);

element.innerHTML = output;
```

The classes `Crow` and `Sparrow` both implement the interface `Bird`, forcing them to implement the `tweet(): string` method. The class `ManWithAHad` does not implement the `Bird` interface, but *by coincidence* has the same method `tweet(): string`. The static method `do(bird: Bird): string` in the class `Chitter` only accepts `Bird` as value. Then all three classes are instantiated and passed over to `Chitter.do(bird: Bird): string`.

Now, there is no error. All three classes are accepted by `Chitter.do(bird: Bird): string`, even the `ManWithAHat` class.

My question is, whether there is any case, where it acutally makes sense for `Chitter.do(bird: Bird): string` to also accept `ManWithAHat` as parameter? My second question, based on this, is whether there is a way in TypeScript to force `Chitter.do(bird: Bird): string` to decline any parameter not implementing the `Bird` interface, regardless whether the structure is the same or not.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: This seems to be the same question with different classes. If you are not happy with that answer I can reopen it, but the idea is the same

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Checked your answer from the other post about duck typing. I don't quite get your answer about adding privates. You say it wouldn't be compilable, but it actually is. And the strange behaviour is still the same. I updated my code example here in this post.

Comment: In your case since `Bird` is an interface you can't add private to it. But the rest of the answer stands. It works because typescript uses structural compatibility.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So there in fact is no way to force the `Bird` interface, because TypeScript only checks the structual and not the named part?